# How many watermelons left with Mr. Bean?

Tags: calculation-puzzle, lateral-thinking

Mr. Bean leaves from place $A$ with 3 sacks that each contains 30 watermelons.
He comes across 30 tolls till he reaches place $B$.
At every toll, Mr. Bean has to give 1 watermelon as toll for each non-empty sack with watermelons.

> How many watermelons are left with Mr. Bean at place $B$?

Hint:

> The answer is not 0.

Comment: Down voters would like to comment?

Comment: Mr Bean is famous for being an idiot. It would be very unlike him to employ an optimal strategy, and since we're not told that he does this doesn't have a unique correct answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> 25

Calculation

> first 10 tolls 30 melons, next 15 tolls 30 more melons next 5 tolls 5 more
>  90 - 30 - 30 - 5
>  First 10 tolls he has 3 sacks so 10 tolls x 3, now he is left with 2 sacks
>  Next 15 tolls, he as 2 sacks si 15 tolls x 2, and he is left with 1 sack with 30 melons and 5 tolls to cross

Comment: I think he could have any number between 0 and your answer, depending on his payment strategy.

Comment: @Hellion I was helping Mr Bean minimize his toll tax.

Comment: If I had to lug 90 watermelons about, I'd want to get rid of them as quickly as possible.  :-)

Comment: Also note that he can eat two watermelons on the journey, and still arrive with the same number.